# Using Autofact to scan assembly and register type by name automatically

Tags: registration, autofac

I have to load a command object from database then execute it. The command in DB looks like (string CommandType, object Parameters).
I registered some commands as following:

```
builder.RegisterType<CommandA>().Named<ICommand>(typeof(CommandA).Name);
builder.RegisterType<CommandB>().Named<ICommand>(typeof(CommandB).Name);

//Resolve
var metadata= GetCommandMetadataFromDB();
var command = _lifetimeScope.ResolveNamed<ICommand>(metadata.CommandType);

//Execute it
var someResult= command.Execute(metadata.Parameters);
```

Here are the questions:

1. How to scan and register all inherited ICommand commands from 3rd-party assemblies by names?
2. It's worked, but it's ugly. Could you suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RegisterAssemblyTypes` method to register types from a given set of assemblies where you can also use the `Named` option to generate the same names as in your manual registration:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(your3rdPartyAssemblies)
       .AssignableTo<ICommand>()
       .Named<ICommand>(týpeToRegister => týpeToRegister.Name);
```